# Format code to align with its own subsection clause

Tags: intellij-idea, code-standards

### Currently using **IntelliJ 2018.2.3**.

What option(s) in the Code Style (or anywhere else) should be checked/unchecked to achieve the following behavior?

**Intended behavior:**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other == this // short circuit if same object
            || (other instanceof UniquePersonList // instanceof handles nulls
               && this.internalList.equals(((UniquePersonList) other).internalList)); <--
}
```

**Current behavior**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other == this // short circuit if same object
            || (other instanceof UniquePersonList // instanceof handles nulls
            && this.internalList.equals(((UniquePersonList) other).internalList)); <--
}
```

Currently, everytime when I auto format the code, it shifts the `&&` to be align with `||`. But it is clear that the `&&` belongs to the subsection of the 2nd clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Binary expressions | **Align when multiline**.